# Strange UV Unwrapping Problems (n-gons?)

Tags: uv

I have this sort of drum/cylinder with spoke-like things supporting it from an inner cylinder. The part I'm having trouble with is the inner cylinder, from which the spokes protrude. I've separated the UVs for the spokes from the inner cylinder, but when I UV unwrap the cylinder UVs look horrid. I won't bore you with details, because the attached blend will probably make more sense anyway, but here's the problem, as shown when the UV and mesh selections are in sync:
[image: Mutilated UV map (below); Actual mesh (above)]

I've already checked for and removed some non-manifold geometry but as this obviously isn't an organic shape it wouldn't be likely anyway. Some of the segments of this cylinder are semi-OK and can fairly easily be fixed by manipulating the UVs, but my question is "why?". Also, I'd prefer to stick to traditional UV mapping with seams et al. rather than "Smart" UV Mapping (I've tried it and the rest of my mesh doesn't unwrap as well then). Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: With that section selected rotate the view until you are looking straight at it and use *unwrap->Project from view*

Comment: Oh, thank you! It worked great with orthographic projection!